# Javascript function doesn't wait until the end of promises

Tags: javascript, django, asynchronous, promise

I have got a function that invokes when a button is clicked, and I am trying to fetch data through API upon clicking. and below is the function that gets triggered onclick. I have to fetch data through API once and then based on a field from the fetched data, I need to fetch another data from another data table. so, I have designed my coding as below, and my console looks like this:

And the console looks like this:

All done []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

1466 (customer_id logged during for loop)

1663 (customer_id logged during for loop)

I thought based on the promise logic, all done should have been read in the end, am I missing anything here?
so Ideally, Alldone console should have invoked at the end containing data fetched based on customer_ids 1466, 1663.

I am not sure what I am missing, I am new to javascript as well as stack overflow, so detailed answer would be so much appreciated.

```
  function test(pmt_id, crm_supplier_id) {
  const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/creditor-detail/'+pmt_id+'/supplier/'+crm_supplier_id+'/'
  let promises = [];

  const results = fetch(url)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(function (item) {

    var list = item;

    for (var i in list) {
      promises.push(getCustomer(list[i].customer_id));
      console.log(list[i].customer_id)

    }
  })
  
  Promise.all(promises)
      .then((results) => {
        console.log("All done", results);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        
        console.log(err)
      });
}

//second function

function getCustomer(customer_id) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer-detail/' + customer_id+ '/';
  fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then((item) => resolve(item))
    .catch
```

Comment: To troubleshoot. Try using Promise.allSettled() it will return the status of each promise. Promise.allSettled(promises). then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status))); Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: I don't think it solves the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run the `Promise.all` part before you even push anything into the `promises` array, since the latter part runs asynchronously. You'd need to move the `Promises.all` part into a `.then`:

```js
const results = fetch(url)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(function (item) {
  var list = item;
  for (var i in list) {
    promises.push(getCustomer(list[i].customer_id));
    console.log(list[i].customer_id)
  }
})
.then(() => Promise.all(promises))  
.then((results) => {
  console.log("All done", results);
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Also, just writing `.catch` does nothing, you need to call it and pass a handler:

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then((item) => resolve(item))
  .catch(e => console.error('Something failed!', e)
```

Plus, it makes no sense to use `new Promise` in `getCustomer`, just `return` the promise that comes from `fetch`:

```js
function getCustomer(customer_id) {
  const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer-detail/' + customer_id+ '/';
  return fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then((item) => resolve(item))
    .catch(e => console.error('Something failed!', e));
}
```

But in general, I'd recommend looking into `async`/`await`, it would *greatly* clean up your code and make it much easier to read and understand for yourself:

```js
async function test (pmt_id, crm_supplier_id) {
  try {
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/creditor-detail/${encodeURIComponent(pmt_id)}/supplier/${encodeURIComponent(crm_supplier_id}/`
    const listResponse = await fetch(url)
    if (listResponse.status !== 200) throw new Error(`List request failed with status ${indexResponse.status}`)
    const listResult = await listResponse.json()
  
    const results = await Promise.all(listResult.map(c => getCustomer(c.customer_id)))
  
    console.log('All done', results)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

async function getCustomer (customer_id) {
  const customerResponse = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer-detail/${encodeURIComponent(customer_id)}/`)
  if (customerResponse.status !== 200) throw new Error(`Customer request failed with status ${customerResponse.status}`)
  const customerResult = await customerResponse.json()
  return customerResult
}
```